# Which point(s) in $\mathbb{R}^3$ represent the same point in $\mathbb{RP}^2$?

Tags: geometry

Real projective plane question

Which point(s) in $\mathbb{R}^3$ represent the same point in $\mathbb{RP}^2$ and explain why?

(0, 4, 2), (1, −3, −2), (0, 1, 1/2), (1, −1, −1), (−2, 6, 4), (10, 10, −10), (1/3, −1, −2/3)

---

Is it the points which pass through the origin of one of the plane?

(0, 4, 2), (0, 1, 1/2)??

But isnt any point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ a line??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{RP}^2$ is the set of lines through the origin in $\mathbb R^3$. So you need to figure out which pairs of these points lies on a line through the origin. You can think about this algebraically via the following characterization: the nonzero points $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ lie on a line through the origin iff there is a nonzero real number $\lambda$ such that $(x_2,y_2,z_2)=\lambda(x_1,y_1,z_1)$. For the two points you indicated, you can take $\lambda=1/4$, so these do represent the same point. There are others though, which I'm sure you can spot now.

Comment: $(1,-3,-2) , (-2,6,4)$ and $(1,-3,-2) , (\frac{1}{3}, -1, -\frac{2}{3})$